# JNI to return data by refrence

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am writing JNI wrapper for my native code ,   my   code is fallows

My java native method ->

```
public native static String GetMimo(String input, String out1,
        String out2);
```

My C native method ->

```
jstring Java_test_mimo_mimojni_DataFecth_GetMimo( JNIEnv* env,String input, String output1, String output2);
{

char *outmimoOne , *outmimoTwo;
GetMimo(&outmimo, &outmimoTwo); // My Native code function call , it allocates the memory and fill the data 

return (*env)->(env,outmimoTwo);
}
```

Here I want to return the data outmimoOne to output1 and outmimoTwo to output2 . 
Since I am new to Java , How exactly I can return these both  variables to my java call  as get by reference which we do in C.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object or data structure with two references inside it and return that:

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> {
    private final T1 x;
    private final T2 y;

    public Pair<T1, T2>(T1 a, T2 b) {
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
    }

    public T1 getX() { return this.x; }
    public T2 getY() { return this.y; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I do prefer *returning results as return values*, it is a matter of style in C. If you want to mimic that style in Java, you have to use container objects as parameters. The traditional way has been to pass in an array object with the expectation that the function will set the result into the first element. Since, in your case, you are using String parameters, you can create and pass `java.lang.StringBuilder` objects as parameters and the function can append values.

In either case, you do have to do a fair amount work on the C side with JNI API to get your values set into the parameters objects.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Arguments are passed by value in Java. So the method receives a *copy* of the caller's reference to out1 (and out2). And whatever you assign to this copy won't be visible by the caller since, well, it's a copy.